# UISearchBar not visible until scroll down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uirefreshcontrol

I added a UISearchBar programmatically to my tableHeaderView but it doesn't show on view load.
There's just a blank space above my table content. When I scroll down a little bit, it appears. 
I changed the background color of the tableHeaderView to see if it visible at all - I could see the changed color, so it seems the searchBar itself is invisible.
Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
...
// Initialize the refresh control.
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(refreshData)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// Suchelemente erzeugen
self.searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
self.searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDC.delegate = self;
self.searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
// some attempts to make it visible
self.searchBar.hidden = NO;
self.searchBar.layer.hidden = NO;
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

Ok, found out, that the refresh control causes the problem.
In viewWillAppear a method is called which updates the title of the refresh control. When I comment this line, the searchbar appears:

```
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
```

So, how to make them both work??

Comment: are you adding anything else to your tableview header or did you set it's contentOffset to something?

Comment: I assigned a refresh control to the table view controller’s refreshControl property. I'm not sure if it's also placed in the tableview header?

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I do, but not for the search bar or refresh control.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it by :

```
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a refresh control and set this as tableview's refresh control. In this way, the attributed text of the `self.refreshcontrol` is not set.

```
UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:GetLocalizedString(@"REFRESH_TO_RELEASE_TITLE", nil)];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshViewPulled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl=refresh;
```

Comment: Please format your code block using 4 spaces rather than a backtick.

Comment: Nice. I was setting the self.refreshControl directly and creating a local variable first and then setting it worked. Not quite sure why that doesn't still give the self version attributed text, but hey, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by pragmatically adjusting the content offset so that rubber band scrolling animation is triggered, causing the UISearchBar to reappear.

If it is invisible, try this:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your trying to add 2 things to the same spot because you never really specified a frame for either, even though the UIResultsController knows where it goes, it can be altered, and the UIControlEventValueChanged [dragging down] is probably causing discrepancies with the frames changing. So I would suggest implementing your search bar through storyboard since you stated you are using it. Drag and drop a Search Display Controller below the Navigation Bar but above the Table View, you will see your cursor change to a green plus, that means you can drop it there (which in this case is the tableViewHeader):

[image: pic1]

Then you should be able to continue pragmatically altering the UIRefreshControl per normal

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(refreshView:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull down to Refresh.."];
}
```

Now there should be no conflicting frame changes to two items added to the same location.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed hint. Tried it, but nothing changes. My next attempt would have been to use IB for the refreshControl too, but that would mean changing a lot in my project, because it is yet defined in a superclass of my tableViewController - maybe this is the problem...

Comment: @Markus you don't have to make a UIRefreshControl in IB